# Group data into different partition even though different repetitive values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data similar to this:

```
Arrange Id  |  Begin Date | End Date | Dept Id
------------+-------------+----------+-----------
 11345         01/02/2001   02/03/2003   2230
 11345         02/03/2004   04/05/2005   2230
 11345         04/06/2005   06/06/2006   2210
 11345         05/06/2007   07/09/2008   2210
 11345         08/09/2009   11/23/2010   2230
 11454         04/01/2008   04/07/2008   1100
 11454         04/08/2008   05/06/2009   1100
 11454         05/07/2009   07/09/2010   1300
 11454         08/07/2011   10/23/2012   1100
```

Expected output:

```
 Arrange Id | Begin Date | End Date    | Dept Id
------------+-------------+----------+-----------
 11345        01/02/2001   04/05/2005   2230
 11345        04/06/2005   07/09/2008   2210
 11345        08/09/2009   11/23/2010   2230
 11454        04/01/2008   05/06/2009   1100
 11454        05/07/2009   07/09/2010   1300
 11454        08/07/2011   10/23/2012   1100
```

I want data to be partitioned based on `Arrange Id`, I need to take `Min(Begin Date)`, `Max(End Date)` dates for each `Arrange id`, `Dept Id`.. But `Dept Id` is repetitive like initially 6620, 6630,6640 then again 6620 etc..

I need to show the values as per expected output shown above.. If I partition based on `Arrange Id, Dept Id` group by for example in above case 11345 , 2230 dept id I am getting single value but i need two different value as shown above..

Can anybody help me on this solution by writing a SQL query (for Oracle)?

Comment: Why 1st row and 3rd row is repeating ,If you are taking `Min(begindate)` and `max(enddate)` for each `arrangeid` and `deptid` combinations? Shoudn't it be in one row like `11345,01/02/2001,11/23/2010,2230` instead of 2 rows?

Comment: Thanks for Reply.. But for other requirement I want to display data similar to output above..For example  in another table look Date 04/04/2004 with in range in to this data then I want Dept Id : 2230  if Date 04/08/2006 then I want Dept 2210 , If Date 09/09/2009 then I want Dept Id : 2230 for Arrange Id: 11345..  If I take min, max directly I am getting 01/02/2001 , 11/23/2010 for dept 2230 for Arrange id : 11345 which is wrong.. Hope this clarifies..

Comment: This is going to be pretty difficult, there'll be some WINDOW_FUNCTIONS in the solution so I'd read up on them if I were you. Is it safe to assume that the records you want to group happen one day apart? I.e. the EndDate of the first record is one day before the StartDate of the next record?

Comment: @AllenSolley, if that is requirement you can do the manipulation in the other table. For e.g, `select * from mytable where to_date('04/08/2006','mm/dd/yyyy') between begindate and enddate` -- gives 2210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you've got to maintain the order of your set in order to do what you want. So I'm using a row number and a rank to find the particular islands you're looking for. This relies on the assumption that your groups are separated by other ArrangeIDs:

```
SELECT arrangeid, 
       MIN(begindate) AS BEGINDATE, 
       MAX(enddate)   AS ENDDATE, 
       deptid 
FROM  
    (
        SELECT arrangeid, 
               begindate, 
               enddate, 
               deptid, 
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY arrangeid, deptid ORDER BY rn) AS grp 
        FROM   (
                SELECT arrangeid, 
                       begindate, 
                       enddate, 
                       deptid, 
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY arrangeid ORDER BY begindate) -
                       RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY arrangeid, deptid ORDER BY begindate) AS rn 
                FROM   arrange
                ) rawdata
    ) ranked 
GROUP  BY arrangeid, 
          deptid, 
          grp 
ORDER  BY arrangeid, 
          deptid
```

Which gives the output:

```
ARRANGEID   BEGINDATE               ENDDATE                 DEPTID
11345       2005-04-06T00:00:00Z    2008-07-09T00:00:00Z    2210    
11345       2009-08-09T00:00:00Z    2010-11-23T00:00:00Z    2230
11345       2001-01-02T00:00:00Z    2005-04-05T00:00:00Z    2230
11454       2008-04-01T00:00:00Z    2009-05-06T00:00:00Z    1100
11454       2009-05-07T00:00:00Z    2010-07-09T00:00:00Z    1300
11454       2011-08-07T00:00:00Z    2012-10-23T00:00:00Z    1100
```

You can find the fiddle heree: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/17b162/49

Comment: Hi Jim Jimson.. Many thanks for your help and providing SQL Query.. Awesome.. This is what I am looking for.. It work for my requirement..

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, where you have to combine begins and ends.

The idea is to find rows that start an island.  You can do this by finding "begins" that have no overlap with existing rows.  Then, accumulate the count of these and aggregate:

```
select arrange_id, dept_id, min(begin_date), max(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date >= begin_date then 0
                      else 1
                 end) over (partition by arrange_id, dept_id) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end_date) over (partition by arrange_id, dept_id
                                       order by begin_date, end_date
                                       rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                      ) as prev_end_date
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by arrange_id, dept_id, grp;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your help on this.